# Why does accessing View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN on a v15 device not crash?

Tags: android

According to the android documentation, [View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) got added in v16. I added this line to my code and run it on a v15 emulator

```
Log.e("Test", "View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN: " +View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Interestingly enough, it does not crash and actually outputs the correct value (4). How is that possible?

Comment: Its a constant, so its probably being optimized to its value in your code from whatever target API you're using, rather than actually being queried from the class.  Its unlikely to actually work.

Comment: Ah here we go. Yea that makes perfect sense :-)

Comment: As @GabeSechan described, the value is a compile-time constant and thus the value is inlined in the compiled class. This is the same reason you can always use something like `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)` to check if you're at or above a certain platform level: the version code is inlined by the compiler, but `SDK_INT` is not.